# ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.MissingNode cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.Arraynode

Tags: spring-integration, classcastexception

I have a reader that maps data from instagram to my system. When performing Junit Test I ran into ClassCastException. My test class has the following code:

```
public class InstagramToJsonMapperTest extends AbstractMapperTest {

private InstagramMapper instagramMapper;
private boolean printResult = true;

@Before
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();
        instagramMapper = new InstagramMapper(128);
    }

    private void compareJson(String unmapped, String mapped) throws Exception {
        JsonNode unmappedJson = loadJson(unmapped);
        JsonNode mappedJson = loadJson(mapped);
        Message<JsonNode> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(unmappedJson).build();
        Message<JsonNode> resultMsg = instagramMapper.map(msg);
        JsonNode result = resultMsg.getPayload();
        if(printResult) {
            System.out.println("processed: " + result);
            System.out.println("expected: " + mappedJson.toString());
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(JacksonUtils.equals(result, mappedJson));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPhoto() throws Exception {
        compareJson("/mapping/test.json", "/mapping/test_mapped.json");
    }

}
```

The error is because of this line in my mapper:

```
String[] branches = JacksonUtils.toArray((ArrayNode) extractor.extract("contentBranch"));
        if(branches.length == 1) {
            abc.put("contentBranch", branches[0]);
        } else {
            abc.set("contentBranch", JacksonUtils.arrayToArrayNode(branches));
        }
```

My problem is, I dont know what to change. Should I change my mapper code or the code in my test file. The error is:

```
ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.MissingNode cannot be 
    cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.Arraynode
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `JsonNode node = extractor.extract("contentBranch")`, then test what actual node type is returned.

In your case, you are getting a `MissingNode` which can't be cast to an `ArrayNode`.

```
if (node instanceof ArrayNode) {...}
else {...}
```